# Product License not initialized error when trying to open an SDE connection in ArcObjects

Tags: enterprise-geodatabase

I am trying to connect to create connection in using ArcObjects using the code below.

```
IPropertySet propertySet = new PropertySet();
IWorkspaceFactory sdeWsFactory = new SdeWorkspaceFactory();

propertySet.SetProperty("SERVER", server);
propertySet.SetProperty("INSTANCE", instance);
propertySet.SetProperty("DATABASE", database);
propertySet.SetProperty("USER", user);
propertySet.SetProperty("PASSWORD", password);
propertySet.SetProperty("VERSION", version);

IWorkspace WS = sdeWsFactory.Open(propertySet, 0);
IFeatureWorkspace fws = WS as IFeatureWorkspace;
```

When it tries to execute the Open, I get the error message: The Product License has not been initialized. How do I tell which "product" it is talking about?

We are runnuing ArcSDE 9.3.1 SP2.

Comment: Are you running this in Desktop or Engine?

Comment: Are you initializing a license using AoInitializeClass?

Comment: You can read up in initialization here: http://resources.esri.com/help/9.3/ArcGISDesktop/dotnet/2efb9e94-81b7-4088-af80-602ca92a2bb1.htm#CompCheck

Comment: I'm not really sure the answers to your questions. We are using AGS but we thought it might be more efficient to connect directly to SDE in some cases.  Does that help?

Comment: Where are you executing the code?

Comment: Could be that your SOC machine is not properly licensed.

Comment: The code is running in a web app.  I'll double check on the SOC machine but I assume it is properly licensed.  Now we do not have a license for ArcGIS Engine and I've seen some references to that with regards to this type of problem while doing searches online.

Comment: I've found a similar question but I'm don't think that the answer is correct http://forums.esri.com/Thread.asp?c=158&f=2276&t=267575

Comment: When using ArcObjects in a standalone app you need to check out the license as has been said. If this code runs on a web app (i.e. on the web server), you will need to create all ArcObjects in the server context using IServerContext.CreateObject.

Answer (score 2):

I think Jay is correct.  Try some code like the following:

```
        AoInitialize init = new AoInitialize();
        // initialize an ArcGIS Server license if the license is available
        if (init.IsProductCodeAvailable(esriLicenseProductCode.esriLicenseProductCodeArcServer) == esriLicenseStatus.esriLicenseAvailable)
            init.Initialize(esriLicenseProductCode.esriLicenseProductCodeArcServer);
        // throw an exception if the license is not available
        else 
            throw new Exception("ESRI ArcGIS Server License is unavailable or has failed");
```